# Set inclusion – proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $K_s := \{(x,y) \in R^2:  x^2 + (y-s)^2 \le s \}$ for $s \ge 0$. Prove, that:

$\{(x,y) \in R^2: y \ge x^2 \} \subset \bigcup_{s \in N}K_s \subset \bigcup_{s\in(0,\infty)}K_s=\{(x,y): y\ge x^2 -\frac{1}{4}\}$

I perfectly know what all the sets look like, but I struggle a bit in naming it in the set's theory language. I could put $y =x^2$ into the $x^2 + (y-s)^2 \le s$ and check if there are always 4 roots, but I guess it is not the best way to deal with this problem. And it won't work for succeeding inclusions.

Comment: What is a root of x > 0?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You're the one who invented the notion of an inequality.  What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

Let's rephrase the three things you have to prove.

**Task #1**: Prove
$$
\{(x,y) \in R^2\colon y \ge x^2 \} \subset \bigcup_{s \in N}K_s.
$$
In other words, prove
$$
\text{If } (x,y)\in \{(x,y) \in R^2\colon y \ge x^2 \} \text{, then there exists $s\in N$ such that } (x,y)\in K_s.
$$
In other words, prove
$$
\text{If } y \ge x^2 \text{, then there exists $s\in N$ such that } x^2+(y-s)^2 \le s.
$$

**Task #2**: Prove
$$
\bigcup_{s \in N}K_s \subset \bigcup_{s\in(0,\infty)}K_s.
$$
In other words, prove
$$
\text{If there exists $s\in N$ such that } (x,y)\in K_s \text{, then there exists $s\in(0,\infty)$ such that } (x,y)\in K_s.
$$

**Task #3**: Prove
$$
\bigcup_{s\in(0,\infty)}K_s=\{(x,y)\colon y\ge x^2 -\tfrac{1}{4}\}.
$$
In other words, prove
$$
\text{There exists $s\in (0,\infty)$ such that } (x,y)\in K_s \text{ if and only if } x\in \{(x,y)\colon y\ge x^2 -\tfrac{1}{4}\}.
$$
In other words, prove
$$
\text{There exists $s\in (0,\infty)$ such that } x^2+(y-s)^2 \le s \text{ if and only if } y\ge x^2 -\tfrac{1}{4}.
$$

Hopefully these rephrasings help you connect the set-theoretic statements with the algebraic understanding you seem to already have.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I have already proved the **Task #1**, as I got $x_1^2 = -1+s$ and $x_2^2 = s$. But what can I do with the **Task #2** and **Task #3**?

Comment: Well, in **Task #2** I thought of: $\bigcup_{s \in (0, \infty)} = \bigcup_{s \in N} + \bigcup_{s \in R_+ - N}$, so $\bigcup_{s \in N} \subset \bigcup_{s \in (0, \infty)}$

Comment: Yes, though I encourage you to get out of the habit of writing $+$ where you mean set-union.

Comment: That's completly true, my mistake. And the third one? putting $y=x^2 - 0.25$ into $x^2+(y-s)^2 \le s$ leads me to $s>0.25$, as Wolfram says.